# Import Numpy in Canopy Express gives error

Tags: numpy, canopy

I am not able to debug this error:

> import numpy as np
>   ImportError: cannot import name multiarray

I get this only when using Canopy Express. Tried 
-Uninstalling and Re-installing Enthought Canopy
- Uninstalling and Re-installing numpy
- Uninstalling and re-install Python 2.7
- Upgrade set up tools and similar things

I tried using MS Visual Tools and importing Python and it worked fine

please help..

Answer (score 0):

Found solution. I had to go to Packages and Install the necessary packages in Canopy Express.

Numpy works fine now.

thanks!